# nginx http -> https redirect adding extra comma with the host name

Tags: nginx, https

I have a server that should always serve https and I try to make nginx automatically redirect from http to https. reading other questions on this subject here, I wrote the following config:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name         *.amazonaws.com *.mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate         /home/ubuntu/mysite/ssl.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key     /home/ubuntu/mysite/ssl.key;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
                autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/mysite/__staticfiles;
    }

    location / {
        include         proxy_params;
        proxy_pass      http://unix:/home/ubuntu/mysite/mysite.sock;

        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

note that the *.amazonaws.com server_name is so I'll be able to use amazon Public DNS, eg "ec2-12-345-678-9.compute-1.amazonaws.com"

now here's the problem: when I enter any http address with the amazon dns, for example this:

```
http://ec2-12-345-678-9.compute-1.amazonaws.com/admin
```

I'm getting redirected to this:

```
https://%2A.amazonaws.com/admin
```

and if I go to https:

```
https://ec2-12-34-567-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com/admin
```

I'm getting here:

```
https://ec2-12-34-567-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com%2Cec2-12-34-567-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com/admin/
```

what am I doing wrong?

thanks,